PowerPoint shows "Error exporting file as PDF: The online service is not available in your region." (Germany, Mac)
I am using Microsoft® PowerPoint for Mac (Version 16.90 (24101387)) with an "Office LTSC Standard for Mac 2021" License (no corporate). I am on a MacBook Pro with Sequoia (15.0.1 (24A348)). After the latest update and restart of PowerPoint today, I am unable to export my slides to PDF anymore, getting the following error message (I am in Germany):

Any ideas what to do about that? Exporting to PDF is crucial for me. It also happens if I am offline.

I assume you don’t have any applications installed like Adobe Acrobat?

No, don't have. Why?

For years Microsoft Office supported printing to a PDF but required an application like Acrobat. This later changed, so this suggests, something else is going on. I would have to research possible corporate group policies, before I provide an answer

If you create a new copy of the slide deck can you convert or print to PDF?

No, same error. And if I create a new presentation from scratch, same error.

I suggest you install older version of Office for a check. The installation package: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/update-history-office-for-mac#release-history-for-office-for-mac

This problem is related to latest update 16.90.
I solved it with downloading and manual install PowerPoint install package 16.89 from
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/update-history-office-for-mac
Direct link
https://officecdn.microsoft.com/pr/C1297A47-86C4-4C1F-97FA-950631F94777/MacAutoupdate/Microsoft_PowerPoint_16.89.24091630_Updater.pkg

You have to remove the PowerPoint.app and then do the install, it won't just downgrade. But this solved the problem – thanks!

I’m experiencing the same issue, but I'm based in the UK. This might be linked to macOS Sequoia.
When exporting to PDF in PowerPoint, there are two options: “Best for electronic distribution” and “Best for printing.” The latter uses macOS’s built-in PDF renderer (the same as Print > Save as PDF). This still works.
The “Best for electronic distribution” option uploads the file to Microsoft’s servers for processing, which then returns a PDF. While “Best for printing” can be used as a workaround, it doesn’t retain hyperlinks, and the resulting file size is quite large.
I suspect this issue is related to macOS Sequoia. PowerPoint might be unable to correctly access the required online service or get the correct region, potentially causing the error? This started for me right after upgrading to Sequoia. So far there is nothing on this online, but I've reported the issue to Microsoft.
If you can access PowerPoint Web, try opening your document and Save as PDF from there. This works for me.

Faced the same issue here, and my solution is to use 'print' option and find the 'PDF' button at the bottom. Select save as PDF and it then bypass the adobe.

For some weird reason I faced the same problem.
Best and fastest free solution is to download WPS Office (https://www.wps.com), where you can convert your powerpoint, doc, or excel to PDF.
I've used WPS for a year now and they're pretty impressive.
Good luck
